# Custom error message in hibernate validator 4.x

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I am using `validation-api` version `1.1.0.Final` and `hibernate-validator` version `4.3.1.Final` in my application. This is my model class which I need to validate

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class User {

@NotEmpty(message = "Zipcode  is empty")
@Pattern(regexp = "^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$", message = "Zipcode value ${validatedValue} is invalid. Expected value {regexp}")
private String zipcode;
```

But the `${validatedValue}` is not getting printed. I somehow want to get the validated value along with the message in my `beanclass` when I call `validator.validate(..)`.

From a `blog`, I have read that "`Hibernate Validator 5` requires the `Unified Expression Language (EL)` in version `2.2` or later. While `Tomcat 7` provides `EL 2.2` out of the box, `Tomcat 6` only comes with an `EL 2.1` implementation which does not work with `Hibernate Validator`."
But for some reasons, I cannot upgrade the `hibernate validator version` to `5.x` as I am using a custom deployment server and not Tomcat.